# How does the spawn protection in Counterstrike Global Offensive work in Competitive Gamemode?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

We had someone matched up with us in competitive mode in Counterstrike Global Offensive who was not content with our performance and started calling us idiots and noobs, the works. We tried to get him to shut up first, then muted him.

As a consequence he started griefing our team. He repeatedly team attacked and deliberately team flashed in the spawn area, probably in an effort to get us to attack him back.

One of my friends reacted to him - unfortunately - by returning fire on being team attacked. Nothing happened then, but in a later round he wanted to flash the griefer back in spawn and hit him with the flash nade (thereby inflicting damage), whereupon he was immediately kicked from the game. It struck us as rather unfair but I guess this has to do with the way spawn protections are implemented in CS:GO.

I guess my friend was actually griefing himself when he returned the favour, so to speak, but it just seems the original griefer should have been kicked a lot earlier.

This is why I would like to know the actual rules at play here. When and where do you have to team attack and how much damage does it have to be for you to be kicked?

I would like to tag more specifically but the existing tags don't seem to be any more specific than that, and I can't create more.

Comment: My understanding is that this kind of thing is relatively new to CS:GO.  I don't know the exact details about it.

Comment: As far as I know it has nothing to do with something like spawn protection rather than that it depends on how often in a specific time you attack a teammate. If you would fire a teammate over and over again even after the bomb has been planted you would get kicked as long as enemys are alive (personal experience)

Answer (score 3):

Usually, after dealing a grand total of 300 damage to teammates overall, or dealing 60-100 ( unsure of exact value) damage to teammates at round start, a kick is issued.

If someone is a jerk like this, mute him, report him, and ignore him. Simple as pie.

Hope this clears up any questions that you have.

Comment: Btw round start means 5-10 seconds from start (don't know the exact time)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to fight back at him, you should kick him instead since a bot would be better than a teammate flashing you. If you have your own team, I guess kicking him out of the server would be very easy.

Comment: That might be true but it's not an answer to the question

Comment: Yea, but I guess getting angry by random dude would not make your day better... Just my opinion.

Comment: @Leosch It's not answer to the question in the title, but it is answer to the users problem, which is dealing with trolls. Nothing wrong with users offering an alternative solution to whatever the users core problem s. In fact this is  perfect example of why including context in your question can lead to better answers.